# Publishing node_modules in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, node-modules

I'm using a devexpress reporting widget that requires node_modules folder, the folder is not visible on my solution explorer until I click on "Show all files"... the issue is when I published initially I got an error of the node_modules directory not found, and when I contacted devexpress support, I was asked to right click on node_modules folder and click "Publish node_modules" to fix that error but when I do so I get this error:

```
Preparing to publish files...
Connecting to bin\Release\PublishOutput...
Unable to open the Web site 'bin/Release/PublishOutput'.  The Web site 'bin/Release/PublishOutput' does not exist.
Unable to open the Web site 'bin/Release/PublishOutput'.  The Web site 'bin/Release/PublishOutput' does not exist.
```

I do not know anything about node_modules other than I need for my reports to display. Any help/explanation would be appreciated. By the way my project is an Asp.Net Core web app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DevExpress, but generally speaking you never include `node_modules`. There should be some mechanism for "publishing" the JS code, such that any dependencies are pulled into the actual published JS, and you don't need `node_modules`. For example, you might have an npm build task or something else like Gulp or Grunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed the issues thanks guys, i just deleted most of the folders in the node_modules that the devexpress reports do not require and inclufed the folder in my project